# EU citizen with US wife and Daughter moving to France

Tags: france, switzerland

I am an EU citizen (Irish) married to a US citizen living in the US with a 1yr old daughter born in the US and with a US passport. My wife's company has an office in Geneva and I am wondering how easy it would be to do the following: Move to France with my wife and daughter and for my wife to work in Geneva. I at first would not be working. We have savings that should cover the "sufficient resources" needed for France.

How difficult would this be?

Comment: Interesting question. You can definitely move to France, but your wife's French residence permit might not allow her to work in Switzerland. She might need a separate Swiss work permit. I don't know. All the cross-border workers I know are EU citizens.